How can I subclass a TButton to owner-draw it?
I want to color a TButton control in C++Builder. I am trying to follow the information I found that suggests using SetWindowLong() to enable the BS_OWNERDRAW style for my TButton control, then catch the WM_DRAWITEM message.
While I do see messages for the button, no WM_DRAWITEM message ever appears.
I am using the following code:
__fastcall TMainForm::TMainForm(TComponent* Owner)
  : TForm(Owner)
{
  OldButtonWndProc  = bTest->WindowProc;
  bTest->WindowProc = NewButtonWndProc;

  SetWindowLong(bTest->Handle,
                GWL_STYLE,
                GetWindowLong(bTest->Handle,
                              GWL_STYLE) | BS_OWNERDRAW);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TMainForm::NewButtonWndProc(TMessage &AMsg)
{
  if (AMsg.Msg == WM_DRAWITEM)
  {
    Beep();
  }
  else
  {
    OldButtonWndProc(AMsg); // default handling.
  }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

I can only assume that the BS_OWNERDRAW flag is not performing its magic. I captured the GWL_STYLE before and after to ensure the BS_OWNERDRAW flag was being set. It is, as far as I can tell. I also checked to see that no other BS flags were set, and they weren't.
Perhaps GWL_STYLE is not the place to set this flag?

You should be using (Get|Set)WindowLongPtr() instead, otherwise your code may not work correctly in a 64-bit build.
In any case, the BS_OWNERDRAW flag is working fine. The WM_DRAWITEM message is simply being sent to the button's parent window instead, which is why you are not seeing it in your subclass.  You need to handle the CN_DRAWITEM message instead, which the parent window will reflect back to the button.
Also, be aware that if the button (or the parent Form) ever recreates its HWND dynamically at runtime (which can happen), you will lose your BS_OWNERDRAW style unless you reset it on the button's new HWND.  A better way to handle this situation is to derive a new class from TButton and have it override the virtual CreateParams() and WndProc() methods, eg:
class TMyButton : public TButton
{
protected:
    void __fastcall CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params);
    void __fastcall WndProc(TMessage &Message);
};

void __fastcall TMyButton::CreateParams(TCreateParams &Params)
{
    TButton::CreateParams(Params);
    Params.Style |= BS_OWNERDRAW;
}

void __fastcall TMyButton::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
  if (Message.Msg == CN_DRAWITEM)
  {
    Beep();
  }
  else
  {
    TButton::WndProc(Message);
  }
}

Or, you could just use TBitBtn instead, which already has the BS_OWNERDRAW style applied to it.
